# Mysql Varchar to GMT Date time value conversion

Tags: mysql, varchar, datetime-format, gmt, string-to-datetime

I appologize for asking this question, but i have searched and kind find anything specific to my needs. I have worked with it but can not seem to make ends meet.

I have a column `SrcFileName (VarChar(100))`

It is populated with filenames (i.e. AB20120928.143815458.txt)
The AB does not change and the extension (.TXT) does not change.

I am trying to convert that SrcFileName to a DateTime value. This is a GMT timestamp.

`str_to_date(Date_Field,'AB%YYYY%MM%DD.%HH%MM%SS.txt')` Does not work, I believe I need to use `Str_to_Date` in conjunction with `Convert()`.

Any assistance Appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it, just use SUBSTR to get the correct part of the string to parse and use STR_TO_DATE on that;

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(SrcFileName,3,15), '%Y%m%d.%H%i%s') FROM TableA;
```

Comment: Thank you Joachim! I understand your approach and it works flawlessly. I appreciate the quick response!